# Sql problem with my query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT    
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_firstname, dbo.pi_employee.emp_lastname, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_no, dbo.pi_employee.emp_cnic, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_currentadd, dbo.pi_employee.emp_cellph, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_birthday, pi_jobtitle_1.jobtitle_name, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_joindate, dbo.pi_education.edu_degree, 
   dbo.pi_education.edu_year, dbo.pi_employee.emp_pension, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_age, dbo.pi_employee.emp_service, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_terminate, dbo.pi_employee.emp_termdate, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_basicofpay, dbo.pi_employee.emp_terminationreason, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_terminationdate, dbo.pi_employee.emp_status, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_gender, dbo.pi_employee.emp_maritalstatus, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_paymethod, dbo.pi_employee.emp_leaveentitle, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_confirmation, dbo.pi_employee.emp_title, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_basicamount, dbo.pi_salgrade.salgrade_name, 
   dbo.tbl_emp_status.StatusName, dbo.pi_skills.skill_type, 
   dbo.pi_location.loc_name, pi_location_1.loc_name AS wcity, 
   dbo.pi_jobtitlehist.jthSaleGradetype, dbo.pi_workexp.exp_serperiod, 
   dbo.pi_employee.emp_domicile, dbo.pi_skills.skill_type AS Skill, 
   dbo.pi_skills.skill_exp, dbo.pi_education.edu_degree AS Degree, 
   dbo.pi_education.edu_uni, dbo.pi_education.edu_distinction, 
   dbo.pi_lochistory.lhstart_date, dbo.pi_lochistory.lhend_date
FROM         
   dbo.pi_location 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_workexp 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_employee ON dbo.pi_workexp.emp_no = dbo.pi_employee.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_jobtitlehist ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_no = dbo.pi_jobtitlehist.emp_no ON 
                  dbo.pi_location.loc_id = dbo.pi_employee.emp_location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_salgrade ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_salgrade_id = dbo.pi_salgrade.salgrade_id   
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tbl_emp_status ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_status = dbo.tbl_emp_status.StatusID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_skills ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_no = dbo.pi_skills.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_location AS pi_location_1 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.pi_lochistory ON pi_location_1.loc_id = dbo.pi_lochistory.loc_id ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_no = dbo.pi_lochistory.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_education ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_no = dbo.pi_education.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_jobtitle AS pi_jobtitle_1 ON dbo.pi_employee.emp_jobtitle_id = pi_jobtitle_1.jobtitle_id
```

I am writing sql query to implement different scenario, but problem is that it gives repeated values. I write distinct and order by too but result was same can any one help me to solve this issue.

---

**EDIT** – The same query with table names aliased:

```
SELECT    
   em.emp_firstname, em.emp_lastname, 
   em.emp_no, em.emp_cnic, 
   em.emp_currentadd, em.emp_cellph, 
   em.emp_birthday, jt.jobtitle_name, 
   em.emp_joindate, ed.edu_degree, 
   ed.edu_year, em.emp_pension, 
   em.emp_age, em.emp_service, 
   em.emp_terminate, em.emp_termdate, 
   em.emp_basicofpay, em.emp_terminationreason, 
   em.emp_terminationdate, em.emp_status, 
   em.emp_gender, em.emp_maritalstatus, 
   em.emp_paymethod, em.emp_leaveentitle, 
   em.emp_confirmation, em.emp_title, 
   em.emp_basicamount, sg.salgrade_name, 
   es.StatusName, s.skill_type, 
   L.loc_name, L1.loc_name AS wcity, 
   jh.jthSaleGradetype, we.exp_serperiod, 
   em.emp_domicile, s.skill_type AS Skill, 
   s.skill_exp, ed.edu_degree AS Degree, 
   ed.edu_uni, ed.edu_distinction, 
   Lh.lhstart_date, Lh.lhend_date
FROM         
   dbo.pi_location AS L
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_workexp AS we
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_employee AS em ON we.emp_no = em.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_jobtitlehist jh ON em.emp_no = jh.emp_no ON L.loc_id = em.emp_location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_salgrade AS sg ON em.emp_salgrade_id = sg.salgrade_id   
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tbl_emp_status AS es ON em.emp_status = es.StatusID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_skills AS s ON em.emp_no = s.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_location AS L1 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.pi_lochistory AS Lh ON L1.loc_id = Lh.loc_id ON em.emp_no = Lh.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_education ed ON em.emp_no = ed.emp_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.pi_jobtitle AS j ON em.emp_jobtitle_id = j.jobtitle_id
```

Comment: Please reformat so as to make this query readable - and if you could state which values are repeating that'd be all the more helpful!

Comment: 10 joins? Are you sure you need that many?

Comment: You need to specify an `ON ......` clause for all your JOINs - that's missing from a great many of your JOINs. Also: **please use table aliases!!** it makes reading such a HUGE statement just all that much easier!

Comment: take a fresh napkin, and start drawing your DB architecture from scratch .. this will not fly

Comment: employee name, cnic ,start, date, end date, age these vales are repeating

Comment: Your query is not enough for someone to figure out what you want your result to be. A tip from me is that you start with one table, probably `pi_employee`. Make sure that you get what you want from that table and then start adding the other tables one at a time. You will notice when you start to get duplicate rows and then you need to figure out what to do about that. Either accept that there will be duplicates or decide which row you want from the latest added table, perhaps the latest, and use a sub query to get just that row for each row on the left side of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, since you're doing a crap ton of Cartesian products with those joins without on clauses, that will cause plenty of what seem like 'repeated values', but are really just the product of the two tables combining sets.

Comment: You are mistaken. Every JOIN there has its corresponding ON clause. It's not so obvious because some joins look like this: `...table0 JOIN table1 JOIN table2 ON condition2 ON condition1...`. This is a valid syntax in SQL Server, it's just slightly obscure without parentheses. (Compare with this: `...table0 JOIN (table1 JOIN table2 ON condition2) ON condition1...`, i.e. you are actually joining the result of another join back to the most left table.)

Comment: SQL server?  That explains my ignorance to the sitch, then.  Oracle and My only.